# mapreduce job stuck at map 100 (using tuple values)

Tags: java, hadoop

I do not know what is wrong with my code.it stuck at map 100%
The input:

```
expression, number
1+2+3, 0.4
```

The output should be:

```
count   expression    number
1 1+2+3 0.4
2 3*4   0.8
```

This is the `map` method:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    inputs = value.toString();  
    tokens = inputs.split(",");
    expr = new Text (tokens[0]);
    fit = new DoubleWritable(Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]));
    EF.setExpr(tokens[0]);
    EF.setFit(Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]));
    count++;
    context.write(new IntWritable(count),EF );    
}
```

and class `Reduce`:

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<IntWritable,exprfit,IntWritable,exprfit> {
  private exprfit EF = new exprfit();
  private int count;

  public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<exprfit> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    EF.setExpr(values.iterator().next().getExpr());
    EF.setFit(values.iterator().next().getFit());
    context.write(key, EF); 
  }
}
```

class `exprfit`:

```
public static class exprfit implements Writable {
  private String expr;
  private Double fit;// type of output value

  public String getExpr() {
    return expr;
  }

  public void setExpr(String expr) {
    this.expr = expr;
  }

  public double getFit() {
    return fit;
  }

  public void setFit(Double fit) {
    this.fit = fit;
  }

  @Override
  public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeChars(expr);
    out.writeDouble(fit);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.toString();
  }

  public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    expr =in.readLine();
    fit = in.readDouble();  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the reducer start? Any errors in the logs?

Just an idea:
It could be readLine() that stalls you... I would try using the `writeString()` and `readString()`, instead of `writeChars()` and `readLine()` for writing/reading expr in your Writable implementation, from the [WritableUtils class](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableUtils.html). It would also be a good idea (at least in the old API) to override methods `get()` and `set(Writable value)` in your exprfit class.

You can also store your counters as VIntWritable, instead to IntWritable, to save some space (if needed), or even short.

More comments: In the Reducer, I would initialize EF inside the reduce() method and remove the count, as it is not used.
I am not sure that you need Map/Reduce for this task.

Comment: thank you. I did not have writestring() or readstring(). I will improve my program to call a method to do mutation on each expression.